# how to change service options in controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-service, ionic-popup

I'm working on an ionic app, I have written an angularjs service for [ionic confirm popup](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/),

**service**

```
   app.factory("PopupSer", ["$rootScope", "$ionicPopup",
      function ($rootScope, $ionicPopup) {
         return {
            delete: function () {

               $rootScope.popup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                  title: 'Delete Title', 
                  cssClass: '',
                  subTitle: '',
                  template: '',
                  templateUrl: '',
                  cancelText: 'No',
                  cancelType: '',
                  okText: 'Yes',
                  okType: 'button-balanced'
               });
            }, // delete

            hide: function () {
               $rootScope.popup.hide();
            }

         }; // return
      }
   ]);
```

Now, I want to change (for example) **confirm title**, **cancelText** or **okText** in my **controller**, something like this:

**controller**

```
PopupSer.delete({
    title: 'Are You Sure About That?'
});
```

How can I do this when I call service in my controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend a "default options" object ([doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend)):

```
app.factory("PopupSer", ["$rootScope", "$ionicPopup",
  function ($rootScope, $ionicPopup) {
     return {
        delete: function (options) {
           var default_options = {
              title: 'Delete Title', 
              cssClass: '',
              subTitle: '',
              template: '',
              templateUrl: '',
              cancelText: 'No',
              cancelType: '',
              okText: 'Yes',
              okType: 'button-balanced'
           };
           $rootScope.popup = $ionicPopup.confirm(angular.extend(default_options, options));
        }, // delete

        hide: function () {
           $rootScope.popup.hide();
        }

     }; // return
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `options` parameter to the delete function.
This way you can customize the `title`, `cancelText`, `okText`, etc.

### ES5

```js
app.factory("PopupSer", ["$rootScope", "$ionicPopup",
    function ($rootScope, $ionicPopup) {
        return {
            delete: function (options) {

                $rootScope.popup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: options.title || 'Delete Title',
                    cssClass: options.cssClass || '',
                    subTitle: options.subTitle || '',
                    template: options.template || '',
                    templateUrl: options.templateUrl || '',
                    cancelText: options.cancelText || 'No',
                    cancelType: options.cancelType || '',
                    okText: options.okText || 'Yes',
                    okType: options.okType || 'button-balanced'
                });
            }, // delete

            hide: function () {
                $rootScope.popup.hide();
            }

        }; // return
    }
]);
```

### ES6 (use [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters))

```js
app.factory("PopupSer", ["$rootScope", "$ionicPopup",
    function ($rootScope, $ionicPopup) {
        return {
            delete: function (title = 'Delete Title', cancelText = 'No', okText = 'Yes') {

                $rootScope.popup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title,
                    cssClass: '',
                    subTitle: '',
                    template: '',
                    templateUrl: '',
                    cancelText,
                    cancelType: '',
                    okText,
                    okType: 'button-balanced'
                });
            }, // delete

            hide: function () {
                $rootScope.popup.hide();
            }

        }; // return
    }
]);
```

Notice that I also use [property shorthand notation](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand) for `title`, `cancelText`, and `okText` properties in the ES6 code.